# Do ajax calls in an each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a webpage and I'm having 5 checkboxes on this page. With a whileloop I'm running through all the selected checkboxes and will perform a AJAX call when checked.

The problem is that the order of the checkboxes is important. Or at least the first AJAX call must do something special before the other AJAX call can be done. However it seems that all the AJAX call are done in the right order, the PHP code behind is not executed in the same order which causes that the fist AJAX call is for example executed as third.

How will I be able to get this right? Below my code.

```
$("#submitforms").click(function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    var first = "true";
    var formsSend = 0;
    var formsToSend = $(":checkbox:checked").length
    var ids = "";
    console.log("To send: "+formsToSend);
    $('span.postable').each(function(index){
      console.log(index);
      add = $(this).find('[name="cc"]').is(':checked');
      if(add){
        btn.css("background-image", "url(/images/wait.gif)");
        btn.html("You will be redirected in a second!");
        sku = $(this).find('.sku').val();
        price = $(this).find('.price').val();
        XID = $(this).find('[name="XID"]').val(); 
        $.ajax({                            
          type: "POST",
          url: "/addtocart",   
          data: {sku:sku, qty:"1", price:price, XID:XID, first:first}   
        }).done(function(data) {
          formsSend++;
          console.log("Forms send: "+formsSend + " > "+index);
          if(formsSend >= formsToSend){
            // redirect to cart here after all forms have been posted
            console.log("forward");
            window.location.href = '/cart';

          }
        });
        first = "false";
      }
    });
```

In the console the following is shown.

```
To send: 5
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
Forms send: 1 > 4 
Forms send: 2 > 0 
Forms send: 3 > 2 
Forms send: 4 > 1 
Forms send: 5 > 3 
forward
```

As you can see, it sends form 1 with index 0, so the first
Then it sends form 2, with index 4, then form 3 with index 2, etc.

So the order of where the forms are "done" is different from how they should be > 4,0,2,1,3 instead of 0,1,2,3,4. The order is each time different.

With the parameter `first` I wanted tel the script `/addtocart` that it's the first one in line so it should do something special. But unfortunately the first on is not always the first one.

**BTW:**

The order is not so important, the only thing that is important is that in the script `/addtocart` I must know that it's the first one.

Comment: I have often used a recursive (pseudo) async function, that takes a list of async call information and calls itself on Ajax completion with the list (minus it's head, via slice).

Comment: I could also set a php session in the `addtocart` script and unset it in the `cart` page. Then if the session is not set, it means it's the first call. However I'm not sure if that's the way to go!

Comment: If the checkbox data depends on eachother, why can't you send it in a single call? Not sure if separate ajax calls are warranted.

Answer (score 2):

every ajax function will return a promise object make use of that. `promises` will contain all the ajax promises and `$.when` will resolve all the ajax calls and fire the callback `done`;

try this

```
$("#submitforms").click(function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    var first = "true";
    var formsSend = 0;
    var formsToSend = $(":checkbox:checked").length
    var ids = "";
    var promises = new Array(); // creating the array for promise.
    console.log("To send: "+formsToSend);
    $('span.postable').each(function(index){
      console.log(index);
      add = $(this).find('[name="cc"]').is(':checked');
      if(add){
        btn.css("background-image", "url(/images/wait.gif)");
        btn.html("You will be redirected in a second!");
        sku = $(this).find('.sku').val();
        price = $(this).find('.price').val();
        XID = $(this).find('[name="XID"]').val(); 
        var promise = $.ajax({                            
          type: "POST",
          url: "/addtocart",   
          data: {sku:sku, qty:"1", price:price, XID:XID, first:first}   
        })
       promises.push(promise);// pushing the promise to the array
      }
    });

    $.when.apply($, promises).done(function(){
          window.location.href = '/cart';
    });

});
```

Comment: you've forgotton the bit where `first` is set to false.

Comment: But $.when won't keep request order, as i'm aware of

Comment: @Wolff it is mentioned in the question that "The order is not so important"

Comment: While `promises` are a really good idea, loads of parallel Ajax calls can be a bottleneck on mobile (it can simply drop requests after the first few). That's why I came up with the recursive Async solution outlined in another answer to keep full control over the loading.

Comment: @AntoJSubash The order is not so important, but the first one must be send first. I believe the order is now again random.

Comment: if the first call is important then place the first `ajax` before `each` and then call the each in the first ajax calls `done` callback. by this way once the first call is completed all the other calls will be fired at random. hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you restructure your loop so that is simply collects the data needed for the Ajax calls in an array, you can use a recursive function to process the Ajax calls **in sequence**. This has the benefit that it happens async so does not block any other processing.

This is a quick hack together of this concept and your code...

```
$("#submitforms").click(function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    var first = "true";
    var formsSend = 0;
    var formsToSend = $(":checkbox:checked").length
    var ids = "";
    console.log("To send: " + formsToSend);
    var queue = [];
    $('span.postable').each(function (index) {
        console.log(index);
        add = $(this).find('[name="cc"]').is(':checked');
        if (add) {
            btn.css("background-image", "url(/images/wait.gif)");
            btn.html("You will be redirected in a second!");
            sku = $(this).find('.sku').val();
            price = $(this).find('.price').val();
            XID = $(this).find('[name="XID"]').val();
            queue.push({
                sku: sku,
                qty: "1",
                price: price,
                XID: XID,
                first: first
            });
        }
    });
    // Now process the queue of data and do processing once all request are completed
    ProcessQueue(queue, function () {
        formsSend++;
        console.log("Forms send: " + formsSend + " > " + index);
        if (formsSend >= formsToSend) {
            // redirect to cart here after all forms have been posted
            console.log("forward");
            window.location.href = '/cart';
        });
    });
});

// Recusively process the Ajax calls (actually this is just chained Async)
function ProcessQueue(queue, callback) {
    if (queue.length) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/addtocart",
            data: queue[0]
        }).done(function (data) {
            ProcessQueue(queue.slice(1), callback);
        });
    } else {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Apologies for not taking into account your counters etc, but this should point you in the right direction (and is a generally useful technique).

While using promises is a great option, it becomes a bottleneck (especially on mobile) if you try to run loads of parallel ajax loads. I often fallback to sequential Async using this technique.

Comment: I understand OP statement like this too +1 Oops, didn''t saw the BTW part of question

Comment: Please note I just changed pop() to [0] as it was processing the wrong end of the queue (was treating it as a LIFO stack... whoops) :)

Comment: I get an error on the line `ProcessQueue(queue, callback){` Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {. Putting `function` in front of it fixes the issue. However I still can't get the code working. It is not giving any errors, but I think `ProcessQueue` is not executed

Comment: @Timo002: Yes, I have no way of executing your code so there will be typos :) Are you debugging in Chrome or something so you can breakpoint? If you can setup a JSFiddle mock-up I can fix any bugs in this (seeing as I put them there). The concept is sound as I have used it many times before but it will be some silly detail I missed. A copy of your page output HTML in a JSFiddle will do for starters.